# Access ASMX webservice without a config file, switch between environments

Tags: .net, web-services, vb6, .net-2.0, asmx

I am restricted to .Net 2.0 on a couple of client PCs that run Windows 2000. (They are running other proprietary stuff that will fail on any other OS)

I would like to be able to access some webservices from a .net DLL that is being called from a VB6 DLL, which is being called by (wait for it) ...  a COBOL app. (I am perfectly aware that this is a sub-optimal environment). My understanding is that I cannot have access to a config file in this situation. I also want to be able to switch between environments.

I would like to be able to create the 2.0 webservice and configure it in code. I have been trolling through google but all i can find are WCF service examples.

Is this possible?
Have you got the code?

Comment: Do you have to use WSE? It's even more obsolete than .NET 2.0.

Comment: I am not vey familiar with these technologies, I thought WSE and 2.0 services were synonomous,maybe I am not using WSE i will check.

Comment: Worse, you might be using WSE 2.0. The latest and least obsolete version of WSE was 3.0.

Comment: I am not using WSE after all.

Comment: You do know that Windows 2000 is end-of-life, right? Do you understand that this means Windows 2000 no longer receives even critical security patches? Moving away from that system altogether should be a top priority, as it's security can no longer have any kind of guarantee behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that a Framework 2.0 web service (In visual studio 2010) does not even need a config file. When you create the web reference it bakes everything in. You can comment out the entire system.serviceModel section in the web config and it will run fine (using defaults). Then you can just set the URL.

```
   Friend Shared Function CreateContractsServiceInstance(UseLive As Boolean) As ContractsService.ContractsWebService

    Dim client As New ContractsService.ContractsWebService()

    If UseLive Then
        client.Url = "http://xxx/livecontracting/WebService.asmx"
    Else
        client.Url = "http://xxx/contractstest/WebService.asmx"
    End If

    Return client

End Function
```

Comment: You don't even need two references. You can just change the Url property of the reference to the URL you want.

Comment: Thanks John, that is much better.